# ImageView slideshow animation

Tags: android

I have a couple buttons under an ImageView within a LinearLayout.  I also have a series of images that I want to play through like a flip book to create an animation.  I do not know anything really about animation and I have no clue how I would accomplish this task. Any ideas and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

I did try to search but my lack of teminology makes it a little difficult..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an array of the images and create a thread to change the image associated to the ImageView every so often. If you need help with that just ask.

~Aedon

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10471479/682778) code snippet would (fade in/out) animate images in a ImageView showing them one after the other. You need to sligthly change the code though, if want to back and forth move the images with the buttons instead of playing a slideshow.